# Notepad++ Regex merged 2 sections into one line delimited

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, regex

I hope I can explain correctly. I have the text below, which consists of 2 sections, 1- the body and 2- the title and each one is separated by a "----" delimited. I am able to mark this data using Notepad++ regex (?s)----(.*?) but for the life of me, I can't figure out on how to merge body and title into one line using 2 sets of delimited lines. The file has over 9K sections.
So the first example set I want to merge looks like - Sharks and Lawyers; Sharks and Lawyers - Q: Why won't sharks attack lawyers?A: Professional courtesy.
Second set - Pig-ipede; Pig-ipede - What do you get when you cross a pig and a centipede?
Bacon and legs.
And as you can see, the text in between "----" varies. Please assist or point me into the right direction. Thank you.

```
Sharks and Lawyers - Q: Why won't sharks attack lawyers? A: Professional courtesy.
----
Sharks and Lawyers
----
Pig-ipede - What do you get when you cross a pig and a centipede?   
 Bacon and legs.
----
Pig-ipede
----
Meals on Wheels - Once upon a time, there was a cat who died.  When she got to heaven, God asked her how she liked being on earth.  She told the Lord that it was awful -- she had to sleep in cold back alleys, where there was no food and life was hard.  God told her that he was sorry it had had turned out that way -- but here, in heaven, she would be happy and He would give her the most comfortable, warm pillow to sleep on.  The cat laid down upon the pillow and was happy. 
 
A few days later, about a dozen mice that came to heaven together and God asked them how they had liked earth.  The earth was no better for them than it was the cat.  They explained to God that it was tough and exhausting and their feet were worn out from always running from cats and dogs and people.  God felt bad for the mice and decided to give them rollerskates.   
One day God sees the cat again and asked her how she was liking heaven.  She explained that it was absolutely wonderful.  The pillow he gave her was the most comfortable place that she had ever slept on, but even better than the pillow were the meals on wheels.
----
Meals on Wheels
----
```

Comment: How do you expect the output to be? Have you tried Power query split by delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([\s\S]+?\R----\R)(.+)\R----\R?`
- Replace with: `$2; $1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
(               # group 1, body text
    [\s\S]+?        # any character, 1 or more times, not greedy
    \R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    ----            # 4 hyphens
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
)               # end group 1
(.+)            # group 2, title
\R              # any kind of linebreak
----            # 4 hyphens
\R?             # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2; $1          # content of group 2 (i.e.: the title) semicolon+space, content of group 1 (the body)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]